# How to apply cross validation on data?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I want to evaluate a ML model using the average cross validation score.

I am splitting the data in a train and test set.

But I don't know if I have to use the train or test data to evaluate the model using the cross validation score.

Here is a part of my code:

```
train, test = train_test_split(basic_df, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)  

# Separate the labels from the features and convert features & labels to numpy arrays
x_train=train.drop('successful',axis=1)
y_train=train['successful']

x_test=test.drop('successful',axis=1)
y_test=test['successful']

model = RandomForestClassifier()

model_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = model, param_distributions = random_grid, n_iter = 100, cv = 5, verbose=2, random_state=42, n_jobs = -1)

model_random.fit(x_train, y_train)


print('Accuracy score: ', model_random.score(x_test,y_test))
print('Average Cross-Val-Score: ', np.mean(cross_val_score(model_random, x_train, y_train, cv=5))) # 5-Fold Cross validation

Y_predicted = model_random.predict(x_test.values)
print('f1_score (macro): ', f1_score(y_test, Y_pred, average='macro') )
```

The main question is on the following code line:

```
print('Average Cross-Val-Score: ', np.mean(cross_val_score(model_random, x_train, y_train, cv=5))) # 5-Fold Cross validation
```

Is it right or should I use the test set there like this:

```
print('Average Cross-Val-Score: ', np.mean(cross_val_score(model_random, x_test, y_test, cv=5))) # 5-Fold Cross validation
```

Comment: Not sure I am following exactly; but we **never** perform CV on the *test* set...

Comment: Okay, that was my question. So the cross_val_score code snippet above is right with the x_train and y_train

Comment: Yes, but you are performing CV 2 times (in `model_random.fit()` and with `cross_val_score`) and, to be honest, not sure what the exact result is when you apply `cross_val_score` to an estimator which is already a CV object, like `model_random` here...

Comment: So how can I get the cross validation score, if I don't use the 2nd line? (the one I wanted to check if I'm correct on)? Would the print('Accuracy score: ', model_random.score(x_test,y_test)) be sufficent?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to fit again to know the performance of your model's performance on training data. you can get using the following command

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(model_random.cv_results_)
```

look at the `mean_test_score` column. Remember this is the performance on test fold of cross validation. This will give you an idea of how well the model performed, for a particular hyper parameter combination chosen by RandomizedSearchCV. Best hyper parameter combination and corresponding model can be extracted using

```
model_random.best_params_
model_random.best_estimator_
```

Coming to your actual test data, usually people don't use cross validation there. 
Just do a prediction there, like how you in this part. In the background, it uses the model_random.best_estimator_ to do prediction.

```
Y_predicted = model_random.predict(x_test.values)
print('f1_score (macro): ', f1_score(y_test, Y_pred, average='macro') )
```

Look at this [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV) for more explanation.